# Integral operator (compactness)

Tags: operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators, compactness, convolution, integral-operators

I am studying the compactness of some convolution operators. Let the convolution
$$ \Gamma: X\longrightarrow X; x\mapsto\int_0^t T(t-s)B(s)x\mathrm{d}s. $$
Here $T(\cdot)$ is a $C_0$-semigroup on some Banach space $X$, $B(s)\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ is a compact operator for all $s\in [0,t]$ and $t\ge 0$.

$\star$ If $B(s)=B$ are independent of $s$, it is not difficult to prove the compactness of $\Gamma$ ( I did it using Riemann summation)

$\star$ I have a positive answer if $s\mapsto B(s)$ is immediately continuous ( continuous in the norm of $\mathcal{L}(X)$).

${\color{blue}\star}$ Now if $s\mapsto B(s)$ is strongly continuous what can we say about the compactness in this case?

${\color{red}\star}$ Another problem which I am facing right now is if we consider
$$ \Gamma: X\longrightarrow X; x\mapsto\int_0^t T_{-1}(t-s)B(s)x\mathrm{d}s. $$
This time $B(s)$ arrives in the Favard space $\mathbb{F}_1$ associated with the $C_0-$semigroup (so that the convolution makes sense). $T_{-1}$ is the extrapolated semigroup. Do we still recover compactness?

Many thanks.

Comment: Integrals over strongly continuous functions with values in the compact operators are compact. That's a result by Jürgen Voigt (from the 80s or 90s) if I remember correctly.

Comment: [Here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0804.46012) you go.

Comment: Many thanks! That's what I was looking for

Comment: Please note that if you have an additional question, the recommended procedure on MathOverflow is to ask a new question rather than to edit an existing one.

Comment: I copied my comments that answer the original question into an answer box, as comments are not archived (at least not publically available) in the post history.

Answer (score 4):

Integrals over strongly continuous functions with values in the compact operators are compact. That's a [result by Jürgen Voigt](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0804.46012).