# Extrapolated Integral operator (compactness)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators, convolution, integral-operators

I am studying the compactness of some convolution operators. Let the convolution with extrapolation
$$ \Gamma: X\longrightarrow X; x\mapsto\int_0^t T_{-1}(t-s)B(s)x\mathrm{d}s. $$
Here $T(\cdot)$ is a $C_0$-semigroup on some Banach space $X$.

${\bf B(s)\in \mathcal{L}(X,\mathbb{F}_{-1})}$ **is a compact operator** for all $s\in[0,t]$ and $t \ge 0$ and ${\bf B(s)x\in L^1(0,t; \mathbb{F}_{-1})}$  (so that the convolution makes sense),

$T_{-1}$ is the extrapolated semigroup and $\mathbb{F}_{-1}$ is the associated Favard space.

Do we still recover the compactness (or weak-compactness) of $\Gamma$?

(see [Compact convolution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431481/integral-operator-compactness) for the case without extrapolation)

Many thanks.